# What is the difference between cy.readFile and cy.fixture in Cypress.io?

Tags: javascript, cypress

What is the difference between cy.readFile and cy.fixture in Cypress.io ? In what context should we use cy.readFile and cy.fixture ?

```
cy.readFile('menu.json')  
cy.fixture('users/admin.json') // Get data from {fixturesFolder}/users/admin.json
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two major differences.

---

#### First, the two functions handle filepaths differently.

`cy.readFile()` starts at your cypress project folder, the folder where your `cypress.json` is. In other words, `cy.readFile("test.txt")` will read from `(path-to-project)\test.txt`.

`cy.fixture()` starts in the fixtures folder. `cy.fixture("test.txt")` will read from `(path-to-project)\cypress\fixtures\test.txt`. Note that this may be different if you have set a fixtures path in your `cypress.json`.

Absolute file paths do not appear to be supported here.

---

#### Second, `cy.fixture()` tries to guess the file's encoding.

`cy.fixture()` assumes the encoding for certain file extensions while `cy.readFile()` does not, **except in at least one special case (see below)**.

For example, `cy.readFile('somefile.png')` will interpret it as a text document and just blindly read it into a string. This produces garbage output when printed to console. However, `cy.fixture('somefile.png')` will instead read in the PNG file and convert it to a base64-encoded string.

This difference isn't in the ability of the two functions, but instead appears to be in default behavior; if you specify the encoding, both functions act identically:

```
cy.readFile('path/to/test.png', 'base64').then(text => {
    console.log(text); // Outputs a base64 string to the console
});

cy.fixture('path/to/test.png', 'base64').then(text => {
    console.log(text); // Outputs the same base64 string to the console
});
```

---

#### Note:

`cy.readFile()` doesn't always read in plain text. `cy.readFile()` [gives back a Javascript object when reading JSON files](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile.html#JSON):

```
cy.readFile('test.json').then(obj => {
    // prints an object to console
    console.log(obj);
});
```